# Java RMI cannot connect to server via WAN while it works in LAN

Tags: java, rmi

I'm working on a project using Java RMI and with a client-server implementation.
On the server side, this is how I initialize my server:

```
final String url = "localhost";
            final int port = 8090;
            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
            IServerGame serverGame = new ServerGame();
            Naming.rebind("//"+url+":"+port+"/undercover", serverGame);
            System.out.println("Server running at //" + url + ":" + port + "/undercover")
```

Undercover is the name of my application. We chose to use the port 8090
arbitrarily.
Now, here is how I initialize the connection client-side:

```
try {
            server = (IServerGame) Naming.lookup("//"+address+":8090/undercover");
            System.out.println("Connected to server " + address + ".");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connection failed.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

`address` is a string in the parameter of the method which initializes the connection and is the IP of the server. We ask the client to enter this IP to allow us to connect to different servers if we want.

When I run my application in local, whether I use localhost or my private IP 192.168.x.x as `address`, everything works fine. The client connects to the server and I can use the application. The problem is that when I want to use the application via WAN, sending the client to a friend and starting the server on my local machine, it doesn't work anymore. I get this error:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: (private IP of host machine); nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

I've already checked a lot of posts in StackOverflow with the exact same problem and the usual answer is to either set the `SystemProperty(java.rmi.server.hostname,"192.168.x.x")` or do it via the `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname` in command line. I'm using Gradle  to compile. I run the application via the run task. The client is a basic fx application too. None of this works unfortunately. I've also tried to open the port 8090 in my firewall but it doesn't solve the problem either.
Now maybe I'm doing this wrong. I've also tried to replace my private IP 192.168.x.x, which is IPv4 that I found via `ipconfig` in the command shell, with my public IP 79.95.x.x. But, again, it doesn't work.
I tried adding the `SystemProperty(java.rmi.server.hostname,"192.168.x.x")` like the first line of code that appears in the server code I showed you above.
I'm connected to internet via 4G. I don't have a box connection, so I can't really go to the box settings to allow certain ports, if that's ever a thing that could fix the issue.

**EDIT :**

So i've tried to switch from naming implementation in server-side to Registry implementation as it was suggested bellow but it didn't make any difference. As i thought it could be just a connection problem, i asked a friend to ping the server with telnet on the port 8090 and in fact it didn't work. He ran telnet [domain name or ip] [port] and the error was :

```
Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

So the problem is that the external clients cannot reach my server or connect to the port. As i'm using 4G as internet connection as i mentioned above, any idea on how i could make the port reachable ?

Comment: Your friend needs to connect to your public IP (google "what's my ip").  You also need to open up the port on your router to allow incoming connections.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! So i've tried to use my public IP but it doesn't work. As i mentioned above i'm only using 4G as internet connection hence i don't have any router on which i can open the port or maybe i can do so but i have no idea how it would work with this type of internet connection. Could you help me up on that point a little bit ?

Comment: There are various points where a connection over a non-standard port can be blocked. It seems to be a network connection issue, rather than specific to RMI, so maybe you can try tools like tracert?

Comment: Ok i'll look that up, what do you mean by non-standard port though ? Replacing 8090 by the default RMI port which seems to be 1099 might solve the problem ?

Comment: Non-standard was probably a misnomer. I was referring to pretty much most of the ports except ssh, http, https, smtp, etc.  :-)

Comment: Carriers like to block most ports other than those I mentioned above, is what I'm getting at I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try using class [java.rmi.registry.Registry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/Registry.html) rather than class `java.rmi.Naming`.

On the server side:

```java
final int port = 8090;
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
ServerGame serverGame = new ServerGame();
IServerGame stub = (IServerGame) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(serverGame, 0);
registry.bind("undercover", stub);
```

On the client side:

```java
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("server host name or IP", 8090);
IServerGame serverGame =  (IServerGame) registry.lookup("undercover");
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, i did try to switch for your implementation but it made no difference, got the same error. Can i know what the difference is between registry and naming implementation ? As i mentioned aboved, i think the problem doesn't come from the rmi itself as it works perfectly fine in local and i can connet to the server and objects are well exported, all the protocol works fine. I think the problem come more from the fact that external clients cannot connect to the server IP or port ( maybe due to the fact i'm in 4G and can't open port on router ? )

Comment: There needs to be a network path between server machine and client machine. Can you [ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) the server machine from the client machine?